# Unable to Draw Feynman Diagram in Beamer Presentation

Tags: beamer, diagrams, tikz-feynman, feynman

I'm using the following code to draw. I compiled using LuaLaTeX and it didn't show any errors, but in the PDF generated no diagram is being shown. Can someone help me out?

I have to compile via LuaLaTex, else other portion of my code won't work. Please help me and if you can tell me the code to draw in LuaLatex for the same diagram.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{2}{6}\selectfont}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
%\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{rules}{Rule}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{}
\title{Negative Dimensional Integral and Modified Method of Brackets}
\author[Sumit Banik]{\textbf {Work By-Sumit Banik\\ \footnotesize Supervised by: B Ananthanarayan}}
\institute{Indian Institute of Science\\Bangalore- 560012}
\date{}
\begin {document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Negative Dimensional Integral Method}
\begin{itemize}
\item Let's now evaluate the massless bubble Diagram:
\centerline{ \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1,baseline, font=\Large,]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[right=3cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram [small] {
            (a1) -- [fermion,edge label={\(p\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion, half left,edge label={\(q\)}] (a5) 
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(p\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion, half left,edge label={\(q-p\)}] (a2)
            };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your code, wrapped in `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` with `pdflatex`, there is no problem. When compiled with `lualatex` I get a lengthy error. Please upgrade your fragment to a full MWE such that we can see why you do not get the error, and can help you. (Notice also that this diagram does *not* require `lualatex`.)

Comment: I just updated it.. Please help

Comment: Your updated code works fine with `pdflatex` but produces an error with `lualatex` on my updated TeXLive 2019 installation. How do you compile, and which installation are you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.0.3. I checked with PDFLaTeX and it compiled with no error. But when I wanted to view PDF it showed 'Error. File not Found'. I don't know what's wrong